# Combining values in a Knockout CSS binding

Tags: knockout.js

I need to bind various values to the CSS of my div:

In the example below, I want to add a CSS value dependant on whether a value is odd or even, a static class called 'highlight', and I also want to add a css class that is based on one of my observables (called 'Name'). It all works until I try to add ProductName(): true

```
<div data-bind="css: { even: $index()% 2 == 0, odd: $index()% 2 != 0, highlight: true, ProductName(): true }">
```

How do I add the observable value's string to the CSS binding?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with knockout 2.2.0. If you are using an earlier version, it won't work:

[See here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/)

You should then be able to do something like:

```
<div data-bind="css: { even: $index()% 2 == 0, odd: $index()% 2 != 0, highlight: true, ProductName }">
```

Assuming the property `ProductName` is the name of a css class.